# What is the right way to reference part of a dataframe after piping?

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the correct way to do something like this? I am trying to get the `colSums` of each group for specific columns. The `.` syntax seems incorrect with this type of subsetting.

```
csv<-data.frame(id_num=c(1,1,1,2,2),c(1,2,3,4,5),c(1,2,3,3,3))
temp<-csv%>%group_by(id_num)%>%colSums(.[,2:3],na.rm=T)
```

Comment: There is already `summarise_each` or `summarise_at` in `dplyr` i.e. `csv%>%group_by(id_num)%>% summarise_each(funs(sum))` or `csv%>%group_by(id_num)%>% summarise_at(vars(2:3), sum)`

Comment: Fantastic, I never knew about the `vars()` syntax before! Would you mind putting that as a complete answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `summarise_each` or in the recent version additional functions like `summarise_at`, `summarise_if` were introduced for convenient use.

```
csv %>%
    group_by(id_num) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum))

csv %>%
     group_by(id_num) %>%
     summarise_at(2:3, sum)
```

If we are using column names, wrap it with `vars` in the `summarise_at`

```
csv %>%
    group_by(id_num) %>%
    summarise_at(names(csv)[-1], sum)
```

NOTE: In the OP's dataset, the column names for the 2nd and 3rd columns were not specified resulting in something like `c.1..2..3..4..5.`

Using the `vars` to apply the function on the selected column names

```
csv %>%
   group_by(id_num) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(c.1..2..3..4..5.), sum)
#    # A tibble: 2 × 2
#  id_num c.1..2..3..4..5.
#    <dbl>            <dbl>
#1      1                6
#2      2                9
```